# Using Match in mysql longitude and latitude search

Tags: mysql, search, latitude-longitude

I'm trying to put together a simple location search where people can enter a keyword and a location and the nearest results are displayed.

I can get the mysql statement for the free text search and the radius search  working individually but not together...

My attempt is below...

```
    SELECT
    place_id, 

(
      3959 * acos (
      cos ( radians(52.586973) )
      * cos( radians( lat ) )
      * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-2.128820000000019) )
      + sin ( radians(52.586973) )
      * sin( radians( lat ) )
    )
) AS distance
FROM places
HAVING distance < 30,

MATCH (title,details) AGAINST ('Cafe') AS score
FROM places 
WHERE MATCH (title, details) 
AGAINST ('Cafe') 

ORDER BY distance
```

Comment: Go read up on SQL basics - if you don't put SELECT, WHERE, GROUP BY, HAVING and ORDER sections in the right order it's not exactly going to work.

Comment: BTW: You are creating a performance nightmare here! Try boxing into a rectangle first, then distance/match!

Comment: Thanks guys - took your advice and got the following working:

SELECT *,MATCH (title,details) AGAINST ('Cafe') AS score, (3959 * acos ( cos ( radians(52.586973) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-2.128820000000019) ) + sin ( radians(52.586973) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM places Having distance <30 AND MATCH (title, details) AGAINST ('Cafe')